# What does the following notion mean in terms of metric spaces?

Tags: metric-spaces

So let (X,d) be a metric space and A $\subset$ X. We have a metric space (A,$D_A$).

What does the following notation mean ? $cl_A(B)$

I think it means the closure of B with respect to the set A, i.e its the closure of B in the metric space (X,d) intersection with the set A.

Comment: See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(topology)): *The closure of a subset $S$ of a topological space $(X,τ)$ denoted by 
$cl_{(X,τ)}(S)$ or $cl_X(S)$.*

Comment: Thank you! @AnneBauval

Comment: Thank you! @DietrichBurde